# shiny doesn't work after, containing javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, renderui

I have a problem with this application, containing a javascript file for the user-interface part, which enables more tabs. However, the server part doesn't work when we have included the javascript file. I have a simple reactivity regarding the mtcars dataset here to showcase the problem. when I disable the "includeScript("script.js")", by merely put the # in front of it, the app works, so the problem is connected to this part. So my question would be, How can I fix this issue and also keep the javascript part in the shiny app.

Grateful for all your help.

Edit:
Now I have replaced includeScript("script.js") with tags$head(tags$script(src="./script.js")), and it appears to work, but with an extremely slow reactivity, I have to wait almost 1-2 min before seeing something. Any suggestion, or do you also experience this ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinymanager)
library(dplyr)
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('[data-toggle=tab]').on('click', function(e){
    let dv = ($(this).attr('data-value'));

    //Set active element in tabcontents
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $('.tab-pane[data-value="' + dv + '"]').addClass('active');

    //Set active element in navbar
    $('a[data-toggle=tab]').parent().removeClass('active');
    $('a[data-value="' + dv + '"]').parent().addClass("active");

    //Close the dropdowns
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Credentials

```
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("Jhon", "Erik"), # mandatory
  password = c("1", "1"), # mandatory
  start = c("2022-02-14"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, "2022-12-31"),
  admin = c(TRUE, TRUE),
  comment = "Model Performance application",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  includeScript("script.js"),
  navbarPage("Shiny",
             collapsible = TRUE,
             theme       = shinytheme('yeti'),
             tabPanel("Information" ,icon = icon("info"),
                      
                      tags$h2("Information about the current user"),
                      verbatimTextOutput("auth_output")
                      
                      
                      
             ),
             tabPanel("Simulation 1",
                      tags$h2("Simulation"),
                      tags$hr(),
                      selectInput("vars", "Variables", names(mtcars), multiple = T),
                      tableOutput("data")
                      
                      
             ),
             tabPanel("Upload",icon = icon("upload"),
                      tags$h2("Upload datasets"),
                      tags$hr(),
             ),
             tabPanel("Simulation 2",
                      tags$h2("Simulation"),
                      tags$hr()
             ),
             
             navbarMenu("Statistical outputs",
                        tabPanel("One"
                        ),
                        tabPanel("Two"
                        ),
                        tabPanel("Three"
                        ),
                        tabPanel("Four"
                        ),
                        tabPanel("Report"
                                 
                        ),
                        navbarMenu("More",
                                   tabPanel("Statistical", icon = icon("info")
                                   ),
                                   
                                   tabPanel("Info",
                                            icon = icon("info-circle")
                                            
                                            
                                   ),
                                   tabPanel("Subpart 4", "Subpart 4"),
                                   tabPanel("Subpart 5", "Subpart 5")
                                   
                                   
                        )
             )
  )
)
```

Wrap your UI with secure_app

```
ui <- secure_app(ui)
```

Server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  output$data <-renderTable({
    req(input$vars)
    mtcars %>% select(all_of(input$vars))
  })
  
}


shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Most important in addition to 1. and 2. from the first answer. The app works as desired only if split in `ui` and `server` part!

It seems that the server part is not working but after clicking on `Statistical outputs` the table appears!

[image]

**First answer:**

1. Put your `script.js` into a `www` folder. This should be in the same folder where your app is.
2. Change `includeScript("script.js"),` in ui part with `tags$head(tags$script(src="script.js")),`

[image]

Comment: I did as you suggested, but now I'm getting errors, I get "Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'req' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Try: `tags$head(tags$script(src="./script.js")),`  Now with `./`

Comment: Try the following: Select all your code and then hit Ctrl+Enter. Does the error still occur?

Comment: I did, the server part does work now, but when I click on more, the tabs are disabled and I can't access them

Comment: Ok, extremely strange, now the more tabs are enabled, but the server part stopped working

Comment: Ok, now sometimes it works, sometimes it's not, very slow reaction, what could be the reason?

Comment: I got it. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it does work as a temporary solution, however, when the app gets bigger, it gives the error no applicable method for 'req' applied to an object of class "character"